# jQuery update content from PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table with a lot of rows, each row has 2 input fields and 1 submit button. When I click on the submit button the data is passed to a PHP script, the PHP script processes the data and returns some text.

Currently the submit button is replaced with the text that is returned by the PHP script. But I want that the returned text is being shown next to the button, so the button doesn't disappear.

I am not able to fix that, maybe somebody can help me with that?

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Add data with Ajax</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).on('click', '#submitButton input[type=button]', function(){
                            var field1 = $(this).parent().parent().find(".field1").val();
                            var field2 = $(this).parent().parent().find(".field2").val();
                            var field3 = $(this).parent().parent().find(".field3").val();

                            var submitButton = $(this);

                            $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "add_data.php",
                                    data: { field1: field1, field2: field2, field3: field3 }
                            })
                            .done(function(msg) {
                                    submitButton.parent().html(msg);
                            });
                    });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" class="field1" value="product 1">
                    <input type="text" class="field2" value="data1">
                    <input type="text" class="field3" value="data2">
                    <div id="submitButton">
                            <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Add">
                    </div>
            </form>
            <form method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" class="field1" value="product 2">
                    <input type="text" class="field2" value="data1">
                    <input type="text" class="field3" value="data2">
                    <div id="submitButton">
                            <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Add">
                    </div>
            </form>
            <form method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" class="field1" value="product 3">
                    <input type="text" class="field2" value="data1">
                    <input type="text" class="field3" value="data2">
                    <div id="submitButton">
                            <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Add">
                    </div>
            </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: you have multiple `id="submitButton"`, which is bad. `id`s are to be unique, and you are going to run into issues later, as javascript/jQuery will not be able to tell which `id="submitButton"` you want to specify. Either change them to `class`s or **unique** `id`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, instead of replacing the content:

```
submitButton.parent().html(msg);
```

append to the content:

```
submitButton.parent().append(msg);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works partly. But the text should also fade out. If I do: submitButton.parent().append(msg).fadeOut(1000); the text fades out, but also the submit button.

Comment: In the HTML, add `<span></span>` immediately after the input tag, then the jQuery expression will be `submitButton.next("span").html(msg).fadeOut(1000);`

Comment: Wow, nice! Almost there. There is problem, when I submit the field it works, but the problem is that I cannot use the same submit again, it simply doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Sinan: If you have additional questions, you may want to ask them separately on Stack Overflow.  The things you're talking about here are not part of the original question and have nothing to do with the problem that was originally presented.  We're happy to help, but comment threads are not meant to act as personal tutors.

Comment: @David: Ok, sorry. I will mark this answer as correct and will not keep asking.

Comment: @Sinan your issue in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722373/jquery-update-content-from-php#comment55215329_33722409) is probably directly related to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722373/jquery-update-content-from-php#comment55214960_33722373). `id`s have a unique purpose, which you are abusing by using the same `id` multiple times.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about clicking the same button again. The `<span>` will still be faded out, so you need `show()` it. Try `submitButton.next("span").html(msg).show().fadeOut(1000);`